# SQL: join last 3 values with matching key to single row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which looks like this:

| id | date | user | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-13 16:42:33.1233 | 1 | '123' |
| 2 | 2022-07-13 16:41:33.1233 | 1 | '12345' |
| 3 | 2022-07-13 16:40:33.1233 | 1 | '12' |
| 4 | 2022-07-13 16:39:33.1233 | 1 | '12365' |
| 5 | 2022-07-13 16:37:33.1233 | 2 | '123234' |
| 6 | 2022-07-13 16:36:33.1233 | 2 | '123' |
| 7 | 2022-07-13 16:35:33.1233 | 2 | '1234' |
| 8 | 2022-07-13 16:34:33.1233 | 2 | '3234' |
| 9 | 2022-07-13 16:33:33.1233 | 3 | '1234' |

I want to get a table with each row of this one and it's user's last(by date) 3 values with a single request.
Resulting table will look like that:

| id | date | user | value | last values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-13 16:42:33.1233 | 1 | '123' | '12345', '12', '12365' |
| 2 | 2022-07-13 16:41:33.1233 | 1 | '12345' | '12', '12365' |
| 3 | 2022-07-13 16:40:33.1233 | 1 | '12' | '12365' |
| 4 | 2022-07-13 16:39:33.1233 | 1 | '12365' |  |
| 5 | 2022-07-13 16:37:33.1233 | 2 | '123234' | '123', '1234', '3234' |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Is there any good way to do it with PostgresSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_agg` as a window function (in `ROWS` mode) and set the window to `3 PRECEDING` and `1 PRECEDING`, partitioned by `user` and ordered by `date`:

```
SELECT *, array_agg(value) OVER w
FROM t
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date
             ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
ORDER BY id, date;


 id |           date           | user_id | value  |    array_agg     
----+--------------------------+---------+--------+------------------
  1 | 2022-07-13 16:42:33.1233 |       1 | 123    | {12365,12,12345}
  2 | 2022-07-13 16:41:33.1233 |       1 | 12345  | {12365,12}
  3 | 2022-07-13 16:40:33.1233 |       1 | 12     | {12365}
  4 | 2022-07-13 16:39:33.1233 |       1 | 12365  | 
  5 | 2022-07-13 16:37:33.1233 |       2 | 123234 | {3234,1234,123}
  6 | 2022-07-13 16:36:33.1233 |       2 | 123    | {3234,1234}
  7 | 2022-07-13 16:35:33.1233 |       2 | 1234   | {3234}
  8 | 2022-07-13 16:34:33.1233 |       2 | 3234   | 
  9 | 2022-07-13 16:33:33.1233 |       3 | 1234   | 
(9 rows)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4729aade00cff2084b82ba3a937cf97d)

Comment: It's very good and I highly appreciate your answer because it does what I asked for, thanks. But if I try to filter this table with 'date > xxx' these aggregated values do not receive values which are behind filter. How can I manage this? Some sort of subquery?

Comment: I did it by myself. Used a subquery in left join.